# CSS nth child style for same class names

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

Trying to apply background "red" for the first child of the class but it applies to all the classes.Tried various ways not sure where I'm wrong.

```css
.worldTime div:first-child.container_1d644347 {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div data-reactroot="" class="worldTime">
  <div class="container_1d644347">
    <div class="description_1d644347">India</div>
    <div>
      <div class="clockContainer_3d7170b9">
        <div id="clock" class="clockContent_3d7170b9">
          <svg class="backgroundNumbers_3d7170b9" viewBox="0 0 226.6 233.8">blah blah</svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-reactroot="" class="worldTime">
    <div class="container_1d644347">
      <div class="description_1d644347">Honduras</div>
      <div>
        <div class="clockContainer_3d7170b9">
          <div id="clock" class="clockContent_3d7170b9">
            <svg class="backgroundNumbers_3d7170b9" viewBox="0 0 226.6 233.8">blah blah</svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why have you appended `.container_1d644347` ?

Comment: Also check your HTML , as presented the 2nd div with class worldTime is a child of the first div with that class, not a sibling. Not all div tags are closed

Answer (score 1):

Do you only want to style the `.container_1d644347` in the first `.worldTime`? Then you need to target it like this:

You also have some weird HTML structure, I don't think you want to nest the `.worldTime` divs in each other. You should rather have them next to each other (added a `</div>` to your HTML to reflect this)

```css
.worldTime:first-child .container_1d644347 {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div data-reactroot="" class="worldTime">
  <div class="container_1d644347">
    <div class="description_1d644347">India</div>
    <div>
      <div class="clockContainer_3d7170b9">
        <div id="clock" class="clockContent_3d7170b9">
          <svg class="backgroundNumbers_3d7170b9" viewBox="0 0 226.6 233.8">blah blah</svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-reactroot="" class="worldTime">
  <div class="container_1d644347">
    <div class="description_1d644347">Honduras</div>
    <div>
      <div class="clockContainer_3d7170b9">
        <div id="clock" class="clockContent_3d7170b9">
          <svg class="backgroundNumbers_3d7170b9" viewBox="0 0 226.6 233.8">blah blah</svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it's a bit different because I'm using SharePoint webparts and trying to apply custom styles. Tried the above method but still it applies style to all classes :(. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What are `all classes`? Is your HTML nesting correct? What div do you want to style exactly? Please add all this infos not as a comment but rather to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple add `:first-child` to the selector (here `.worldTime`). Below is the code

```css
.worldTime:first-child  {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div data-reactroot="" class="worldTime">
  <div class="container_1d644347">
    <div class="description_1d644347">India</div>
    <div>
      <div class="clockContainer_3d7170b9">
        <div id="clock" class="clockContent_3d7170b9">
          <svg class="backgroundNumbers_3d7170b9" viewBox="0 0 226.6 233.8">blah blah</svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-reactroot="" class="worldTime">
  <div class="container_1d644347">
    <div class="description_1d644347">Honduras</div>
    <div>
      <div class="clockContainer_3d7170b9">
        <div id="clock" class="clockContent_3d7170b9">
          <svg class="backgroundNumbers_3d7170b9" viewBox="0 0 226.6 233.8">blah blah</svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this isn't working for me. Tried all the above ways but still colors all classes.